# Putting a variable into a string (quote)

Tags: python, variables, quotes

Help I can't get this to work, I am trying to put the variable age into the string but it won't load the variable properly.

Here is my code:

```
import random
import sys
import os


age = 17
print(age)
quote = "You are" age "years old!"
```

Gives this error:

```
File "C:/Users/----/PycharmProjects/hellophyton/hellophyton.py", line 9
        quote = "You are" age "years old!"
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use a string formatter here, or concatenation. For concatenation you'll have to convert an `int` to a `string`. You can't concatenate ints and strings together.

This will raise the following error should you try:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Formatting:

```
quote = "You are %d years old" % age
quote = "You are {} years old".format(age)
```

Concatenation (one way)

```
quote = "You are " + str(age) + " years old"
```

**Edit**: As noted by J.F. Sebastian in the comment(s) we can also do the following

In Python 3.6:

```
f"You are {age} years old"
```

Earlier versions of Python:

```
"You are {age} years old".format(**vars())
```

Comment: You could skip the `+` signs if they were just between string literals. For example: `"You are" "17" "years old!"` But you need the plus signs to concatenate a string variable and a string literal: `"You are" + age + "years old!"`

Comment: True, but it's just implicit string concatenation. There used to be a slight, very slight, performance improvement but with latest implementation(s) that's not really true anymore. Plus, I think it's bad practice. Explicit > Implicit makes things harder to debug.

Comment: mention `f"You are {age} years old"` in Python 3.6 or `"You are {age} years old".format(**vars())` on earlier Python versions.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it for me!

Comment: @jfs is there a benefit in using the `f"You are {age} years old"` compared with the concatenation `"You are " + age + " years old!"`?

Comment: @carlitos081 for example, the latter may produce the TypeError mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
>>> age = 17
>>> quote = "You are %d years old!" % age
>>> quote
'You are 17 years old!'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `+` sign to insert it into the string like this:

```
quote = "You are " + age + " years old!"
```

You can read more about other ways of doing this on [Python's string documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, please check following code which was asked someone else again.

```
event_type_id = 26420387

### this is original post, need to add variable to 'eventTypeIds'
##events_req_format = '{' \
##             '"jsonrpc": "2.0", ' \
##             '"method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listEvents", ' \
##             '"params": {"filter": {"eventTypeIds": ["26420387"]},' \
##             '"marketStartTime": {"from": "2022-03-12T00:00:00Z","to": "2022-03-13T23:59:00Z"}}},' \
##             '"id": 1' \
##             '}'

# added formatted string with variable event_type_id, used prefix f
events_req_format = '{' \
             '"jsonrpc": "2.0", ' \
             '"method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listEvents", ' \
             '"params": {"filter": {"eventTypeIds": ["'\
             f'{event_type_id}'\
             '"]},' \
             '"marketStartTime": {"from": "2022-03-12T00:00:00Z","to": "2022-03-13T23:59:00Z"}}},' \
             '"id": 1' \
             '}'
```

Str quoted with sing or double quotation is a single line string. So '\' is just make a new line for convenience. And the all the strings quoted by single quotation are making a str, events_req_format.
I just changed the string **{"eventTypeIds": ["26420387"]},'**
As you can see, I added formatted string with prefix f for the variable.